# jQuery UI autocomplete with item and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following script which works with a 1 dimensional array.  Is it possible to get this to work with a 2 dimensional array?  Then whichever item is selected, by clicking on a second button on the page, should display the id of whichever item is selected.

This is the script with the 1 dimensional array:

```
var $local_source = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
$("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete({
    source: $local_source
});
```

This is the script for the button to check the id, which is incomplete:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    // alert($("#txtAllowSearch").someone_get_id_of_selected_item);
});
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to use the ui.item.label (the text) and ui.item.value (the id) properties

```
$('#selector').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($("#txtAllowSearchID").val()); // get the id from the hidden input
});
```

[Edit] You also asked how to create the multi-dimensional array...

You should be able create the array like so:

```
var $local_source = [[0,"c++"], [1,"java"], [2,"php"], [3,"coldfusion"], 
                     [4,"javascript"], [5,"asp"], [6,"ruby"]];
```

Read more about how to work with multi-dimensional arrays here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/literal-notation2.shtml

Comment: So this is not possible to do without a hidden input?

Comment: No because there are two pieces of data: the text and the id.  You can't put both into a single input.  And you usually don't want to show the id to the user, so it needs a input type="hidden" to go into.

Comment: I tried this script, and I am just getting a blank dropdown when I type something into the #txtAllowSearch input field.

Comment: I tried label and value, but it makes no difference, i still get a blank dropdown when I type something into #txtAllowSearch.  However, if I use the array style mentioned by Salman A, I don't get a blank dropdown, but I then end up with the problem with it inserting the id into the #txtAllowSearch instead of the value.

Comment: got it working, had to use value and id and had to use Salman's style array with the labels value and id.

Comment: you have a missing closing bracket in the line: `alert($("#txtAllowSearchID").val();`

Comment: Could you please add to this answer a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 40):

From the Overview tab of jQuery autocomplete plugin:

> The local data can be a simple Array
>   of Strings, or it contains Objects for
>   each item in the array, with either a
>   label or value property or both. The
>   label property is displayed in the
>   suggestion menu. The value will be
>   inserted into the input element after
>   the user selected something from the
>   menu. If just one property is
>   specified, it will be used for both,
>   eg. if you provide only
>   value-properties, the value will also
>   be used as the label.

So your "two-dimensional" array could look like:

```
var $local_source = [{
    value: 1,
    label: "c++"
}, {
    value: 2,
    label: "java"
}, {
    value: 3,
    label: "php"
}, {
    value: 4,
    label: "coldfusion"
}, {
    value: 5,
    label: "javascript"
}, {
    value: 6,
    label: "asp"
}, {
    value: 7,
    label: "ruby"
}];
```

You can access the label and value properties inside [`focus`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus) and [`select`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event through the `ui` argument using `ui.item.label` and `ui.item.value`.

**Edit**

Seems like you have to "cancel" the focus and select events so that it does not place the id numbers inside the text boxes. While doing so you can copy the value in a hidden variable instead. [Here is an example](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html#example-1).

Comment: So is this not possible to do without using a hidden input field?

Comment: #txtAllowSearch is in an `<input type="text" name="xxx">` field, yes? If so then `$("#txtAllowSearch").val()` would give you the id number, not the label text, given that the user has entered something.

Comment: The problem is that if I use the above array, when I click on an item from the autocomplete input field, it puts the value into the #txtAllowSearch field instead of the label.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use a `<select>` element instead?

Comment: Yes, as long as I can use autocomplete on it?

Answer (score 18):

My code only worked when I added 'return false' to the select function. Without this, the input was set with the right value inside the select function and then it was set to the id value after the select function was over. The return false solved this problem.

```
$('#sistema_select').autocomplete({

    minLength: 3,
    source: <?php echo $lista_sistemas;?> ,
    select: function (event, ui) {
         $('#sistema_select').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
         $('#sistema_select_id').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
         return false;
     },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#sistema_select_id" ).val( ui.item? ui.item.value : 0 );
    } 
});
```

In addition, I added a function to the change event because, if the user writes something in the input or erases a part of the item label after one item was selected, I need to update the hidden field so that I don´t get the wrong (outdated) id. For example, if my source is:

```
var $local_source = [
       {value: 1,  label: "c++"}, 
       {value: 2,  label: "java"}]
```

and the user type ja and select the 'java' option with the autocomplete, I store the value 2 in the hidden field. If the user erase a letter from 'java', por exemple ending up with 'jva' in the input field, I can´t pass to my code the id 2, because the user changed the value. In this case I set the id to 0.

Comment: Same was happening to me too. "return false" did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just want to share what worked on my end, in case it would be able to help someone else too. Alternatively based on Paty Lustosa's answer above, please allow me to add another approach derived from this site where he used an ajax approach for the source method

http://salman-w.blogspot.ca/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html#example-3

The kicker is the resulting "string" or json format from your php script (listing.php below) that derives the result set to be shown in the autocomplete field should follow something like this:

```
    {"list":[
     {"value": 1, "label": "abc"},
     {"value": 2, "label": "def"},
     {"value": 3, "label": "ghi"}
    ]}
```

Then on the source portion of the autocomplete method:

```
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("listing.php", {
            term: request.term
        }, function(data) {                     
            var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data.list, function(m) {
                return {
                    label: m.label,
                    value: m.value
                };
            });
            response(array);
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#autocomplete_field").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#field_id").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps... all the best!

Comment: The link was perfect. I was struggling to keep the label in the text field after selecting it so thanks

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the objects in your source array have an id property...

```
var $local_source = [
    { id: 1, value: "c++" },
    { id: 2, value: "java" },
    { id: 3, value: "php" },
    { id: 4, value: "coldfusion" },
    { id: 5, value: "javascript" },
    { id: 6, value: "asp" },
    { id: 7, value: "ruby" }];
```

Getting hold of the current instance and inspecting its selectedItem property will allow you to retrieve the properties of the currently selceted item. In this case alerting the id of the selected item.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($("#txtAllowSearch").autocomplete("instance").selectedItem.id;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#MyTextBox").autocomplete({
        source: "MyDataFactory.ashx",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#MyIdTextBox').val(ui.item.id);
            return ui.item.label;
        }
    });
});
```

The above responses helped but, did not work in my implementation.
The instead of using setting the value using jQuery, I am returning the value from the function to the select option.

The MyDataFactory.ashx page has a class with three properties Id, Label, Value.

Pass the List into the JavaScript serializer, and return the response.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is need to hack around the value and label properties, use hidden input fields or to suppress events. You may add your own custom property to each Autocomplete object and then read that property value later.

Here is an example.

```
$(#yourInputTextBox).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        // Do something with request.term (what was keyed in by the user).
        // It could be an AJAX call or some search from local data.
        // To keep this part short, I will do some search from local data.
        // Let's assume we get some results immediately, where
        // results is an array containing objects with some id and name.
        var results = yourSearchClass.search(request.term);

        // Populate the array that will be passed to the response callback.
        var autocompleteObjects = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = {
                // Used by jQuery Autocomplete to show
                // autocomplete suggestions as well as
                // the text in yourInputTextBox upon selection.
                // Assign them to a value that you want the user to see.
                value: results[i].name;
                label: results[i].name;

                // Put our own custom id here.
                // If you want to, you can even put the result object.
                id: results[i].id;
            };

            autocompleteObjects.push(object);
        }

        // Invoke the response callback.
        response(autocompleteObjects);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Retrieve your id here and do something with it.
        console.log(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

The [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) mentions you have to pass in an array of objects with label and value properties. However, you may certainly pass in objects with *more* than these two properties and read them later.

Here is the relevant part I am referring to.

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported
>   formats: An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ] An array of
>   objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value:
>   "value1" }, ... ] The label property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user
>   selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used
>   for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will
>   also be used as the label.

Answer (score 2):

At last i did it Thanks alot friends, and a special thanks to Mr https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a   because of his code i was able to solve it properly. finally my code is looking like this  as i am using groovy grails i hope this will help somebody there.. Thanks  alot

html code looks like this in my gsp page

```
  <input id="populate-dropdown" name="nameofClient" type="text">
  <input id="wilhaveid" name="idofclient" type="text">
```

script Function is like this in my gsp page

```
  <script>
        $( "#populate-dropdown").on('input', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'autoCOmp',
                data: {inputField: $("#populate-dropdown").val()},
                success: function(resp){
                    $('#populate-dropdown').autocomplete({
                        source:resp,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#populate-dropdown").val(ui.item.label);
                            $("#wilhaveid").val(ui.item.value);
                             return false;
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And my controller code is like this

```
   def autoCOmp(){
    println(params)
    def c = Client.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list {
        like("nameOfClient", params.inputField+"%")
    }

    def itemList = []
    results.each{
        itemList  << [value:it.id,label:it.nameOfClient]
    }
    println(itemList)
    render itemList as JSON
}
```

One more thing i have not set id field hidden because at first i was checking  that i am getting the exact id , you can keep it hidden just put type=hidden instead of text for second input item in html

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I've tried above code displaying (value or ID) in text-box insted of Label text. After that I've tried event.preventDefault() it's working perfectly...

```
var e = [{"label":"PHP","value":"1"},{"label":"Java","value":"2"}]

$(".jquery-autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: e,select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.jquery-autocomplete').val(ui.item.label);
        console.log(ui.item.label);
        console.log(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without the use of hidden field. You have to take benefit of the JQuerys ability to make custom attributes on run time.

```
('#selector').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#txtAllowSearch").attr('item_id',ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($("#txtAllowSearch").attr('item_id')); // get the id from the hidden input
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Auto Complete Text box binding using Jquery

```
  ## HTML Code For Text Box and For Handling UserID use Hidden value ##
  <div class="ui-widget">
@Html.TextBox("userName")  
    @Html.Hidden("userId")
    </div>
```

---

### Below  Library's  is Required

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

---

Jquery Script

```
$("#userName").autocomplete(
{

    source: function (request,responce)
    {
        debugger
        var Name = $("#userName").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/UserNames",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Name: Name

            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                responce(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        $("#userName").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#userId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        return false;
    }
})
```

### Return data Should be  below format

---

```
 label = u.person_full_name,
 value = u.user_id
```

Comment: How to get userId when remove?