# Autocomplete with hidden id field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I did this autocomplete following another post ([How to get JQuery UI Autocomplete work with item id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042090/how-to-get-jquery-ui-autocomplete-work-with-item-id)) and it is working fine for the autocomplete,. The problem is that it's not getting id.

Here is my code:

```
var raw = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.CT));
var source = [];
var mapping = {};
for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; ++i) {
    source.push(raw[i].procedure);
    mapping[raw[i].procedure] = raw[i].id;
}

$('#tags').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: source,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#tagsID').val(mapping[ui.item.id]);
    }
});
```

Array contains 4147 itens.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai -> No, I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it only works with value instead of id... So the final code is like:

```
   var raw = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.CT));

var i;
for(i = 0; i < raw.length; i++){
    raw[i].value = raw[i]['id'];
    delete raw[i].id;
}

var source = [];
var mapping = {};
for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; ++i) {
    source.push(raw[i].procedure);
    mapping[raw[i].procedure] = raw[i].value;
}

$('#tags').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: source,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#tagsID').val(mapping[ui.item.value]);
    }
```

hope that it don't let the application too slow..

Thank you anyway.