# Finding class of value from autocomplete by name

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm trying to work something out but failing to find the right design.
I have an autocomplete text box that combines values from 3 different models: Country,City and University. 
Once the user has selected a value I want to retrieve that object from the DB. My problem is, I only have the name but not the type...

The naive solution would be to look for the value in all three tables, but I'm sure there is a better solution.. Is there a way to maybe send a hash to the autocomplete source with a hiden data-atrribute stating the type?

This is my autocomplete box:

```
<%= text_field_tag :where, nil, data: { autocomplete_source: '/searches/where' }, placeholder: "Where" %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What gem/lib are you using to implement the autocomplete?

Comment: I'm using JQuery UI's autocomplete and the datasource is an action in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up using the ui.item.value property as listed in this question:

[jQuery UI autocomplete with item and id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815330/jquery-autocomplete-with-item-and-id/4815374#4815374)