# Jquery Autocomplete library returning array with no properties from PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am adding an autocomplete library into my project using the `jquery-ui` library.

I created the PHP script from which I need to get the data:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('connection.php');
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$searchTxt = '%'.$_POST['searchTxt'].'%';
$res = array();
$getPatients = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clinic_id = :cid and patient_name_en LIKE :searchTxt ORDER BY patient_id DESC";
$execGetPatients = $conn->prepare($getPatients);
$execGetPatients->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execGetPatients->bindValue(':searchTxt', $searchTxt);
$execGetPatients->execute();
$getPatientsResult = $execGetPatients->fetchAll();

$i = 0;
foreach($getPatientsResult as $result)
{
    $res[$i] = $result;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

And the JavaScript part is here:

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $("#searchTxt").on('keyup', function(){


    searchTxt = $("#searchTxt").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/autoComplete.php',
      data: {searchTxt: searchTxt},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success:function(resp)
      {
        $.each( resp, function(key, result)
        {
          var availableTags = result['patient_name_en'];
        });
      },
      error:function(resp)
      {
        console.log(resp)
      }
    })

  } );
$( "#searchTxt" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

I had the following error in the console about jQuery:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

But now it gone somehow, and I don't know why.

Now after typing in the search text box, I am getting an empty array at the network tab of the developer tool or an array but with no properties and nothing is show as autocomplete near the text box:

[image]

**EDIT**

I changed a line in PHP into:

```
$searchTxt = '%'.$_POST['searchTxt'].'%';
```

[image]

And now no php errors, but a JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: availableTags is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: Try printing the array on the back end side and see if the array gets populated. The problem could be in your SQL query.

Comment: I fixed it now data appears at the network tab but I had the following error, please see the edit in a minute

Comment: Have a look here [How to get value from autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815330/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-item-and-id)

Comment: no, now the data is returned from PHP script normally

Comment: see the dit at the bottom end

Comment: Can you please update what you are receiving as an object in the ajax response?

Comment: Okay wait just half a minute

Comment: you can now see the returned array from PHP and the error at the console

Comment: @droidnation.... Congrats :D It worked I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#searchTxt" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
   });  


success:function(resp)
  {
    $.each( resp, function(key, result)
    {
      var availableTags = result['patient_name_en'];
    });
  },
```

You have declared the availableTags inside the success method of ajax call and you are trying to access it outside it's scope.

Either you make availableTags as global variable or declare somewhere on the top so that you can access it in both the places ( for reassigning after ajax success and in the autocomplete method).

Comment: Okay now a new error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) – droidnation 42 secs ago   edit   ` and a link with what I typed inside the text box as not found too: `The requested URL /ncd/pages/Walid was not found on this server.`

Comment: It means the requested url is not able to serve the request. Please check the ajax call url is correct or not.

Comment: After making all the change did you push your code to some other location??? I am asking this question because I see the requested URL changed from /ncd/php to ncd/pasges/Walid.

Comment: No. How I know if I mistakenly pushed i t?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $( "#searchTxt" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

this code gets executed before your post gets success, it's non-blocking, so you have to write it something like.

```
$( function() {
  $("#searchTxt").on('keyup', function(){


    searchTxt = $("#searchTxt").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/autoComplete.php',
      data: {searchTxt: searchTxt},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success:function(resp)
      {
        $.each( resp, function(key, result)
        {
          var availableTags = result['patient_name_en'];
          $( "#searchTxt" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});

        });
      },
      error:function(resp)
      {
        console.log(resp)
      }
    })

  } ); 
});
```

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: and a link with what I typed inside the text box as not found too: `The requested URL /ncd/pages/Walid was not found on this server.`

Comment: then the issue is with your php code, fix it and it's done