# Passing javascript value to html input tag

Tags: jquery, html, input

I want to pass value from jquery to my html code.

```
function setMembers(members){
var members = members;
$('.member-search').autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
  var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(request.term), "i");
  var recs = $.grep(members, function (obj) { 
    return ((regex.test(obj.first +" "+ obj.last)))
  })
  response($.map(recs, function (item) {
    return {
      label: item.first + " " + item.last,
      value: item.first + " " + item.last,
      id: item.id
    }
  }));
},
}
```

Here in **return** I passed item.first and item.last as **value** and item.id as **id**.  I want to pass this id value to my html input tag value. This is my html.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control member-search" placeholder="Choose team member.." id="assigned_to" name="assigned_to" value="">
```

I can pass item.last and item.first but not item.id. Is there any way to do that.
If I use item.id as **value** of return statement I can pass it to input tag value, But my auto complete out put is wrong. It shows user ID as below.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `item.id + ""`?

Comment: it depends on the autocomplete plugin, but you can certainly add the id into the value and/or label, eg: `value: item.first + " " + item.last+" ("+item.id+")"`

Comment: @NikosM.I just want to pass id to my autocomplete. That is the issue. Is there any way to pass just one part of value?

Comment: @Hatebit I edit my question

Comment: @Dinu please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having some issues with your code. First you don't have to utilize every `jQuery` function; nowadays browsers do have and support `filter` instead of `grep` and arrays do have a `map` method by default. Also, since you have simple text, there is no need to escape the regular expression and thus you can avoid a polyfill for the `RegExp.escape` function. The [`jquery.grep`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, expects a boolean return value, not a string like you returning. jQuery UI [`autocomplete` `source`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option function `response` can return an array of strings (`[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`) or an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties (`[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`).

> **Function**: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
>   Autocomplete, including JSONP. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A `request` object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters
>     `"new yo"` in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal `"new yo"`.
> - A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the
>     provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for
>     simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source
>     callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the
>     `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that
>     the widget always has the correct state.

To refactor your code, I'll use vanilla JS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Please run below snippet to check it working:

```js
function setMembers(members) {
  $('#member-search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

      let regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      
      let recs = members
        // Filter members using request term
        .filter(({ first, last, id }) => {
          let term = `${first} ${last}`;
          return regex.test(term);
        })
        // Map to the response supported object
        .map(({ first, last, id }) => ({
          label: `${first} ${last}`,
          value: id
        }));

      console.log('recs', recs);

      response(recs);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#member-search").val(ui.item.label); 
      $("#selection").text(`"${ui.item.label}" (ID: ${ui.item.value})`);
    }
  });
}

setMembers([{
    first: 'Giorgos', last: 'Mihas', id: 1
  }, {
    first: 'Mike', last: 'Nakas', id: 2
  }, {
    first: 'Angela', last: 'Fox', id: 3
  }, {
    first: 'Maria', last: 'Pappou', id: 4
  }, {
    first: 'Vaggelis', last: 'Maggas', id: 5
  }, {
    first: 'Nikos', last: 'Stergiou', id: 6
  }, {
    first: 'Elvis', last: 'Presley', id: 7
  }
]);
```

```css
h3 { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Members: </label>
  <input id="member-search" class="member-search">
  <h3>Selection: <span id="selection"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: can I pass id to the input id with this?

Comment: @Dinu no, it does not support `id`, but that is the role of the `value`. In your example you don't use value, you just set it with the full name like the label. You can use `value` to store the `id`. Check this Q/A ["jQuery UI autocomplete with item and id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815330/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-item-and-id).

Comment: @Dinu if you look at that Q/A you'll see a kind of a *hack* to use `value` as an `id` and still display `label` to the input. Please check my updated answer and run the code snippet.